# Replacing rhum in baba au rhum

Tags: liqueur, recipe-changing

I have some baba and would like to make baba au rhum. However I don't have rhum at home, and would like to use some other liquors.

How should I go about picking the replacement? Which aspects should I consider?

Answer (score 3):

I can't say I've ever had baba au rhum, but I would expect any sweet liquor would be an adequate replacement and may even offer a more exciting end result than just plain rum. A more straight replacement that comes to mind would be mead, but some more adventurous alternatives might be Bailey's, Grand Marnier, limoncello, or amaretto.

I'd look at your recipe and see what kind of flavor profile you are building, then see what kind of liquor would either accentuate or blend with those flavors. For example, [this New York Times recipe](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1022037-baba-au-rhum) calls for honey, cinnamon, cloves, and orange zest in the syrup. So here are some couch considerations for what I might attempt to replace the rum with:

- Grand Marnier, to lean into the orange zest
- Spiced mead, to compliment the honey sweetness while adding a warm spice that pairs with the cinnamon and cloves
- Limoncello/blue curaçao, to lean into the citrus flavors without making it exclusively orange-flavored
- Bourbon, to add a woody smokiness that can add a touch of savory to the sweetness for a more rounded experience
- Amaretto, along with sliced almonds to give a sweet nuttiness to the dish
- Bailey's/RumChata, to add a creaminess to the syrup (might even also add some powdered sugar to turn it into an icing)
- Wine, specifically a sweet and fruity white, such as a moscato (although a red could also be fun for the visual)
- Kahlua, for a coffee bitterness that can blend nicely with the sweet syrup
- There's also no rule that you only need to use one liquor, either. Bailey's and Kahlua, for instance, is a popular mix for drinks and for good reason.

Ultimately, it comes down to your recipe and your tastes. Check what you have on hand and consider what flavors it will impart on your dish.

Comment: Drambuie might be nice as well